# $G=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^ \infty G_i$ and $G_n \subset G_{n+1} , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ $\implies$ $G$ is not cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $G=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^ \infty G_i$ and $G_n \subset G_{n+1} , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ , then how does one prove that $G$ is not cyclic ? Each $G_i$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You mean $G_n \subsetneq G_{n+1}$, I presume? Suppose $G$ were cyclic, and $g$ a generator of $G$. Then let $k_n$ the smallest positive integer such that $g^{k_n}\in G_n$.

Comment: Are $G_i$ subgroups?

Comment: @ajotatxe: I would guess so, because otherwise you can just take $G_n = [-n, n] \cap \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is cyclic, then there exist $a\in G$ such that $G=\langle a\rangle$. Since $G=\cup_{i=1}^ \infty G_i$, so there exist $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ , such that $a\in G_n$. Thus, $G_n=G=\langle a\rangle$ (as $a$ generates $G$), but since $G_n \subsetneq G_{n+1}$ (is a proper subset), so there exist $b\in G_{n+1}$ with $b\notin G_n=G$, and this is a contradiction.  Hence, $G$ is not cyclic.

Comment: By the same argument, $G$ is not even finitely generated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Proceed by contraposition, assume that $G$ is cyclic (say, $G=\langle g_0\rangle$) and show that in this case the inclusions are not strict.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $G_n \subsetneq G_{n+1}$. If $G$ would be cyclic, then it would have to be the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$. You should prove that we cannot have a properly ascending chain $G_1 \subsetneq G_2 \subsetneq \ldots$ of subgroups in $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. To do this, you could use the fact that any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $k\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $k$.